# How to recover files from command "git clean -df"

Tags: recovery, git

I accidentally run the command "git clean -df", so I lost many directories and files, I want to recover them, I don't have backup in time machine. I tried some software to recover, but they don't work.

Comment: You can't recover files after deleting them. The only way would be to immediately shut down your Mac, WITHOUT modifying ANY part of the HD, then use a HD Recovery Program. You probably already lost your data, as it gets overwritten by new files. Let this be a lesson to use Time Machine or some other backup software, especially when using terminal commands that delete stuff.

Comment: Are you sure that files have been deleted in the online repository? If you are working in the local repository and you have one up-to-dated online, you can download the last online version using `git clone` or  `git pull`.

Comment: @IronCraftMan thank you for your reply, do you know is there some good software for recovering files for mac OS X? I am almost try every method, but failed T.T

Comment: @llyjy21 as I said, you probably already overwrote the data. By installing that other Software, and whatever else you did, OS X could have modified the HD. It's too late. Since every method has failed, I'd give up. Next time backup your data.

Comment: Same question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-undo-a-git-clean-fdx

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with an online repository and you keep it up-to-date you can download all the file from the online repository using the following commands:

```
git pull                            # in the case the remote is set
git clone <address_of_repository>   # in the case the remote is not set
```

Using these commands you'll be able to restore your deleted files, obviously only if the online repository is up to date.

Comment: Nope, I mean it delete all my folders and files in my local machine, not related to git

Comment: In this particular case the only solution is follow what IronCraftMan suggested to you.

Comment: haha, thank you, but i prefer IronMan. haha

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into same issue unknowingly ran git clean -df and git clean -xf, but fortunately I am using php storm and it saves local history by which I am able to recover the deleted files.

If you are also using any IDE then check if it has local history.

Comment: No. The answer is to use a proper backup regime. This covers all files as asked in the question. An IDE might protect some files but that is not its purpose, definitely not non source code files and in the OPs case the backups the IDE keeps might have been deleted as well.